# Cylinder Triangle Intersection

Tags: geometry, intersection-theory

so i have a personal project, for which i need an algorithm which tells me if a given Cylinder and given Triangle intersect with each other. Along these lines;

[image]
Thats an intersection.

[image]
This is also a intersection.

[image]
This is no intersection.

I found some papers which appear to do this, but they all have some downside that dosnt allow me to use it. The most common reason is that these papers only concern themselfs with Planes and not triangle intersections.

I would assume the algorithm for this would need the triangle points p0-p2, the triangle Normal, the cylinder direction and cylinder radius. All of which i can provide in the program, but i sadly dont really know how to make such an algo.

So yeah, any help would be coold :D Thank you for reading !

EDIT; Just to clarify, this algo would be used to determain if a Star with a given radius hits a Pixel. It dosnt matter where the Cylinder intersects the Triangle (2 Triangles = 1 Pixel) just if it does. I hope that makes it a bit simpler...

Comment: Can you parameterize the [triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2218336/parameterization-of-a-triangle-in-mathbb-r3) and the [cylinder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3953681/how-to-get-the-parametric-equation-of-a-rotated-cylinder-with-certain-slope)?

Comment: @user170231 hey ! i am not entirly sure i understand what you mean D:

Comment: I'm essentially asking, can you find / do you have parametric equations for both surfaces using the same coordinate system? The linked questions may help get you started if you don't have them readily available.

Comment: Hm... from what i can find, this is possible for a Cylinder but i dont entirly understand where to go from there. Ill give it a shot though, lets see

Comment: Conceptually, if you could set the Cylinder about the Z axis Then you define the lines of the triangle sides and check if they are not cutting the Cylinder. If none cuts the cylinder you just need to verify that point (0, 0, z) is out of the Cylinder.

Comment: @Moti thats gonna be a bit difficult... Basically the program i have evaluates the size of Pixels and performs Ray-Triangle intersections with a 3D Point Cloud. These points are all over the place pointing in basically all directions, and the Pixels too point all over the place and are not even uniform in size. I can fix them to the center but idk if i can undo the rotational translation...

Comment: @ErikHall - no that is not difficult. You are not comparing all cylinders at the same time against all "Pixels" (whatever you mean by that, which obviously is not its normal definition). You are comparing one cylinder at a time against one triangle. For that cylinder and triangle, you can effectively create a custom coordinate system which makes the checks as simple as possible. Perform those checks, then move on to the next cylinder/triangle pair, and create a new coordinate system for them. Any method you use will effectively amount to doing this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing this for tool path generation for CNC machines. I wanted to find how far down I could go along a given axis before I touched the triangle. Here's what I came up with:-

1. Transform the triangle vertices into 'cylinder' space with the cylinder axis running along the z-axis through the origin.
2. Test if the highest vertex is within the radius i.e x^2 + y^2 < r^2. If so we've found the highest point in the triangle is englosed by the cyclinder
3. Find the highest point where the cylinder intersects the plane of the triangle. Get the normal for the traingle plane from the cross product of 2 edges. Project along this direction from the cylinder center to the cylinder edge. Test if this point is in the triangle - in the xy plane, if so you've found the highest point of intersection.
4. If both these methods fail to find a point of intersection, then the cylinder does not enclose all the vertices (2) and the cylinder isn't enclosed by the triangle (3). If there is any intersection the edges must go through the cylinder walls. Test the triangle edges to see if the line segments intersect with the cylinder. This is a circle-line intersection problem in 2D. The highest of these points will be the highest intersection point of the triangle and cylinder